# Is there an advantage in using a word2vec model as a feature extractor for text clustering?

Tags: cluster-analysis, word2vec, feature-extraction, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I am doing text classification using scikit-learn following [the example in the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/plot_document_clustering.html).

In order to extract features, that is, to convert the text in a set of vectors, the example uses a [HashingVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer) and a [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer) vectorizer.

I am doing a stemmatization before the vectorizer in order to handle different stems of the same word. That is, I would like "running" and "run" to be mapped to the same vectors.

I wonder if there is an advantage in using as a vectorizer a [word2vec model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec) instead. I thought that this would allow me to handle synonyms, that is, to map different words that have the same meaning to vectors very near between each other in the vector space.

Is my reasoning correct, or the following [KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans) alorithm for clusterization will handle synonyms for me?

Comment: The whole reason people use word embeddings is that they are usually better representations for tasks like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, word2vec-based-features sometimes offer an advantage.

But whether & how it can help will depend on your exact data/goals, and the baseline results you've achieved before trying word2vec-enhanced approaches. And those aren't described or shown in your question.

The [`scikit-learn` example you report as your model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/plot_document_clustering.html) doesn't integrate any word2vec features. What happens if you add such features? (As one very clumsy but simple example, what if you either replace, or concatenate into, the `HashingVectorizer` features a vector that's the average of all a text's word-vectors.)

Do the results improve, by either some quantitative score or a rough eyeballed review?

Comment: On a second tought, my texts are scientific, and I don't think a word2vec pre-trained on Google News would have the necessary words in its vocabulary. Can I train a word embedding on my texts and pass the vectors I so obtained as features?

Comment: Yes, and using your own domain's text to train your word-vectors is usually a good idea overall – unless for some reason (1) your data is thin & you think some other external vectors are 'good enough' for your domain; or (2) you need coordinate-compatibility with some larger/broader set of vectors.